# How can I view the bits of a byte in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a printf converter to print in binary format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Consider this small C application

```
int main () {
    int bits = 100 >> 3;    
    printf("bits => %d", bits);     
    return 0;
}
```

How can I print the `bits` variable so I can see it as a binary value (with the bits clearly shifted), e.g. `00001100`?

I'm also learning, so feel free to correct any terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (not tested):

```
#define PRINT_BITS 7

void printbits(int input){
    int i, mask;

    for(i=PRINT_BITS; i >= 0; i--){
       mask = 1 << i;
       if(input & mask){
          printf("1");
       }else{
          printf("0");
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Experienced programmers will usually print the value out in hex (`"%x"` in the format string), because there is a simple correspondence between hex digits and each group of four binary bits:

```
Hex Binary
 0   0000
 1   0001
 2   0010
 3   0011
 4   0100
 5   0101
 6   0110
 7   0111
 8   1000
 9   1001
 A   1010
 B   1011
 C   1100
 D   1101
 E   1110
 F   1111
```

It would do well to commit this table to memory.

Comment: yeah there's very little reason to use straight binary it's too many digits

Answer (score 2):

You have to extract one bit at a time. Something like the following

```
int main() {
  int bits = 100 >> 3;
  for (int bit = 7; bit >= 0; --bit)
    printf("%d", (number & (1 << bit)) == 1);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t this print the bits in reverse order?

Comment: Would have indeed. Thanks for the catch. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to extract the bits one at a time and print them out to the screen.  Here's a simple function

```
void printBits(int value) {
  int bits = sizeof(int)*8;
  int mask = 1 << (bits-1);
  while ( bits > 0 ) {
    putchar((mask & value) ? '1' : '0');
    bits--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int number = 0xEC; 
for (int bit = 128; bit != 0; bit >>= 1) printf("%d", !!(number & bit));
```

If you want to avoid the heavy runtime of `printf` function, just use putchar:

```
putchar(!!(number & bit) + '0');
```